# Of components, shared services and children in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create a shared service between a component and one of it's children (I have a project that has several notes, and want to update a note)

so, in component "A" I do the following

```
import {SharedService} from "../services/my.shared.service";
...
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.scss'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
...
constructor(private _sharedService:sharedService) { }
...
```

I have a route in this component that does

```
this._router.navigate(['./bar'],{relativeTo: this._route});
```

my routes are defined like this

```
{
        path: 'foo/:id',
        component: FooComponent,

        children: [
          {
            path: 'bar',
            component: BarComponent
          }

        ]
      },
```

so, the "Bar" component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from "../services/my.shared.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'bar',
  templateUrl: './bar.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar.scss']
})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService:sharedService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    let item:any = await this._sharedService.getCurrentItem();
    console.log("xxxx",item)
  }

}
```

this all compiles.

However, when I come to click on the button that navigates to `bar`, I get

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet
>   to load 'BarComponent'

Now, I know that is because my `Foo` template does not have a `<router-outlet>`. That is for a reason - I want the bar template to replace the foo template when it is visualised.

I did try setting up the routes as this

```
{
    path: 'foo/:id',
    component: FooComponent
},
{
    path: 'foo/:id/bar',
    component: BarComponent
 }
```

but then I get the error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for
>   SharedService!

So, how do I either

A) replace my foo template with the child bar template
B) fix the provider error ?

New to ng2/4 , routers and outlets, so I may be missing something fundamental

**update #1**
I have thought of putting a `<router-outlet>` into the foo template, and wrapping the parent template with an "*ngIf=inParentMode" but this seems very "hacky"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make up your mind - you mentioned having a `FooComponent` that is replaced by a `BarComponent` through routing. That implies that `FooComponent` and `BarComponen`t are siblings of each other, and your routing should be something like your second routing example:

```
{
    path: 'foo/:id',
    component: FooComponent
},
{
    path: 'foo/:id/bar',
    component: BarComponent
 }
```

But, if `FooComponent` and `BarComponent` are siblings, then you can't share a service between them by declaring a provider in one - by definition, when you declare a provider in a component, you are saying you want a unique instance of that provider for that component and all its **children**. `FooComponent` is a sibling of `BarComponent`, not its parent *(again, based on how you're describing your usage scenario).*

In this case, you have two options:

1. declare the shared service provider in a component that's actually a parent of both FooComponent and BarComponent (from your routing code, that's probably AppComponent), or
2. declare your shared service provider at the NgModule level - which in general is the better way to go for most scenarios *(unless you're explicitly taking advantage of the 'unique instance per component' ability)*.

So, remove the provider declaration of your service from `FooComponent`, and add it to the NgModule declaring these components (probably `AppModule`).

Comment: yeah - thanks. I was hoping that there was a way of getting a child template to replace the parent template (it's not a master/detail view I'm after)

However, I think that perhaps a module for `foo` and it's siblings is the appopriate way to go. Then at least the sharedService can be, ahem, shared, accordingly.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: note that once you provide a service at the module level, that service is available globally to all components, regardless of how they were declared. So, if you are creating a new module solely for provider scoping, you won't get the behaviour you expect. (the presence of lazy loaded modules complicates this slightly)

Comment: all components declared within the module, right ? not all components in the app ?

Comment: services declared in modules are shared amongst all components in the app - regardless of the module they are declared in.  (again, lazy loaded modules are slightly different)

Comment: think, for eg, of HttpModule which provides Http service. You import that module once, and you can make use of the Http service everywhere in your app